# Is it possible to reverse engineer or replay WebRTC connections in the same way that you can for HTTP requests?

Tags: webrtc

Discord recently implemented "Go Live" which is essentially a live-streaming feature that allows users to stream within their respective guilds. However, Discord does not have a public API for this feature so I wanted to create my own for my own purposes. "Go Live" utilizes WebRTC and I was wondering if it is possible to reverse engineer and replay WebRTC connections to help me create my own API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extend you can, but the media will always be encrypted, and it is likely that the API will have session mechanisms and protection to prevent non-official "clients" to join.